# Fourier Transform In Music

Tags: calculus, matrices, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, derivation-of-formulae

I am a senior in highschool and am currently trying to conduct an exploration on Fourier Analysis, specifically using the Discrete Fourier Transform to analyze a chord played on my piano. Basically I'd play a chord of 3 notes, deduce the different frequencies of the sound wave, and estimate the chord played. I am having issues trying to come up with theory to the Fourier Transform, including related math concepts, derivation of the formula, and key math that needs to be understood in order to use the fourier transform. Is there any way someone could help with that as I am a bit unfamiliar to this.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever heard of this book? https://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/d.j.benson/pages/html/music.pdf D.Benson, "Music: a math offering". Maybe that can help you

Comment: Assuming the Fourier transform of $g(t)$ is defined as $$G(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_t[g(t)](\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t)\, e^{2 \pi i \omega t}\, dt\tag{1}$$ then the Fourier transform of $$g(t)=\cos(2 \pi f (t-t_0))\tag{2}$$ is $$G(\omega)=\frac{1}{2} e^{2 \pi i f t_0} \delta(\omega-f)+\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 \pi i f t_0} \delta (\omega+f)\tag{3}$$ so for a chord of $3$ notes you should see prominent spikes in $|G(\omega)|$ at $\omega=\pm f$ where $f$ is the fundamental frequency of each note and probably some lesser spikes in $|G(\omega)|$ at the harmonics of the three fundamental frequencies.